# Bash Script- Issue with variables and | bc

Tags: bash, bc

So I have a variable that I want to compare with another number in an if statement.

```
b=8.25
if [ $(echo "$b < 10" | bc) -ne 0 ]; then
echo "hey"
fi
```

I get the following error

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

I know the issue is having the b variable inside, how can I make it so that I can maintain it in there?

Please help

Comment: It works for me in Bash.  What shell are you using?

Comment: You can try b=$'8.25\r';[ ${b%.*} -lt 10 ] &&  echo "hey"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script file probably has DOS-style CRLF line endings:

```
$ b=8.25
$ if [ $(echo "$b < 10" | bc) -ne 0 ]; then
> echo "hey"
> fi
hey

$ b=$'8.25\r'
$ if [ $(echo "$b < 10" | bc) -ne 0 ]; then
> echo "hey"
> fi
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M
bash: [: -ne: unary operator expected
```

Run `dos2unix` on your script file.

Comment: I am using mobaXterm at my school and I don't have permission to run dos2unix, what else can I do?

Comment: Those 2 facts have nothing to do with each other. Use `sed 's/\r$//'`

Answer (score 0):

Store the comparison in a variable separateley

```
b=8.25

# Capture output outside the if
comparison=$(echo  "$b < 10" | bc)

# Use the output in the if
if [ $comparison -ne 0 ]; then

    echo "hey"
fi
```